# Can we use "indeed" in negative sentences to emphasize the negative point?

Tags: word-usage, negation, adverb-placement

If the answer is "yes", so which one of the following is correct?

> He is not indeed a wise man.
>
> He is indeed not a wise man.
>
> He indeed is not a wise man.

Answer (score 3):

You can use indeed in a negative sentence. In an isolated sentence like this, "indeed" would more likely be in agreement to another's statement.

> He isn't very wise
>
> No, He indeed is not a wise man.

The first one sounds incorrect; the other two are correct, but with slightly different emphases.

> He is indeed not a wise man

The emphasis is more on "not a wise man"

whereas

> He indeed is not a wise man

The emphasis could be instead on "He"

Comment: Your answer was so clear and helpful. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is *yes*.

**Indeed**. *adv*.

*:  truly <… their plan was indeed a risky one. — Lemony Snicket, The Austere Academy>*

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indeed

You may shift the adverb "*indeed*" modifying the verb **is** anywhere in and around the verb *is* which is negated by *not* to mean **is not**, and it won't change anything: all three will mean the same thing.

You start with...

He is a wise man.

Negate the truth of him being *wise*...

He is not a wise man.

Now, place emphasis on the fact he is not *wise*...

And the BEST of the three you present: "He is *truly* not a *wise* man."